# Relationships in POCO entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, poco

I have just setup EF4Templates and generated POCO Entities for my project. I was using normal EF entities before generating POCO entities. I am new to POCO entities and I am sure I have missed a step somewhere. My POCO entites are not picking up the relationships of my DB Model. They were working fine when I was using EF models. For example I have two tables called Appointments and Services. Before using POCO Entities I could access the service of the appointment like this:

```
var svc = appointment.Service;
```

But now it returns a null with POCO. What Am I doing wrong? Will greatly appreciate some help.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need have to have a proxie track the navigation properties. This is done automatically if the navigation properties are declared `public virtural`.

```
class Dog{
  public int Id {get; set;} //CF will automatically recognise this as a primary key
  public virtual <List>Leg Legs{get; set;} //automagical navigation property
}

class Leg{
  public int Id {get; set;} //idem
  public virtual Dog PartOf {get; set;} //automagical navigation property
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how can i declare the navigation properties as public virtual? sorry i am very new to POCO Entities.

Comment: well, just like that ;) I'll edit the answer to be a bit more elaborate.